# How to pass Request and service of request scope into doctrine.event_listener service in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I can't get this to work. I need to have a service of request scope to be available in a Doctrine listener service that tagged as a doctrine.event_listener.

I tried this https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5486 approach, but still no luck.

What I need to work is this service definition:

```
<service id="acme.listener.on_insert" class="Acme\MyBundle\Listener\OnInsertListener">
    <argument type="service" id="my_request_scope_service"/>
    <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="onFlush" method="onFlush"/>
</service>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use synchronized services as described in [How to Work With Scopes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html#using-a-service-from-a-narrower-scope) in the Symfony CookBook.

First you would have to set `my_request_scope_service` as `synchronized`.

Then in your `acme.listener.on_insert` you have to modify the way to inject the service needed with a setter:

```
<service id="acme.listener.on_insert" class="Acme\MyBundle\Listener\OnInsertListener">
   <call mehtod"setYourRequestScopeService">
       <argument type="service" id="my_request_scope_service" on-invalid="null" strict="false" />
   </call>
   <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="onFlush" method="onFlush"/>
</service>
```

Note that, as it's indicated in the docs, you have to deal with a possible `null` value in your listener service and that synchronized services are available since version 2.3.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that, but still can't get it to work. It looks like it can't be done through proper options in Symfony.

Comment: What kind of error does it throws? An scope related exception or when your listener is executed does not recieve your request scope service?